# Strength Parameter in ICAR Spatial Model

Tags: bayesian, spatial, hierarchical-bayesian, stan, car

As I understand it, the parameter $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ that controls strength of spatial association in a CAR model gets set to 1 in an Intrinsic CAR model. Does this mean that an ICAR model cannot/should not have a parameter scaling it?

In particular, and following [this writeup](http://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/icar_stan.html), I've implemented an ICAR spatial prior in Stan using the following code to update:

```
target += -0.5 * dot_self(phi[node1] - phi[node2]);
```

Is there any reason why I can't just stick another parameter $\alpha$ in front of this prior to govern the relative weight of the spatial association compared to other priors in the model (such as hierarchical information)?

Comment: The derivation of the pairwise difference formula assumes $\alpha = 1$; you need to use the formulas in the previous [case study](http://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/mbjoseph-CARStan.html) for the CAR case.

Comment: @BenGoodrich So if I changed the line of code in my question to `target += -0.5 * alpha * dot_self(phi[node1] - phi[node2]);`, I wouldn't be fitting an appropriate model somehow?

Comment: Correct, but it is not too difficult to fit the appropriate model.